# How to apply a custom layout for password pages in Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, passwords

I'm working on an existing project where I need to add a new layout for password pages.  I can't seem to find a complete enough answer to get what I need working.  What I have in application_controller.rb is:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  layout :layout_by_resource

  protected

  def layout_by_resource
    if devise_controller?
      'signin'
    else
      'application'
    end
  end
end
```

From what I read, this needs to somehow be changed to this format:

```
config.to_prepare do
  Devise::SessionsController.layout "devise"
  Devise::RegistrationsController.layout proc{ |controller| user_signed_in? ? "application" : "devise" }
  Devise::ConfirmationsController.layout "devise"
  Devise::UnlocksController.layout "devise"            
  Devise::PasswordsController.layout "devise"        
end
```

...but trying to put that in with what I have either does not work or breaks everything.

Can anyone explain how these pieces fit together?  Where in what I have would the above code go?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No one replied, probably because this was a stupid question.

Once I realized one was intended to go in config (application.rb) and the other in controllers (application_controller.rb) things worked out.